# How to get active tab index from TabContainer

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax, tabcontainer

Currently I am using this line of code in my JavaScript

```
var tabIndex = $(':focus').attr('tabIndex');
```

However this constantly fails to get the active index.

Here is asp:TabContainer header in case this helps. I have also tried document.GetElementById, however to no avail as well.

```
    <asp:TabContainer ID="AdvOrBasicSearch" runat="server" ActiveTabIndex="0">
```

Comment: `:focus` selects the currently focused element in the page. If you want to select the current selected tab in a tab group, there is surely a better way around.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this method works much better. I created a variable with the tabContainer itself. Then, I just needed to go inside the variable and pull the value from the _activeTabIndex property.

```
var tabIndex = $find("AdvOrBasicSearch"); //AdvOrBasicSearch is name of tabContainer
var i = tabIndex._activeTabIndex;
```

Answer (score 2):

They say a picture is worth a thousand words...

I have used jQuery here. With it it is simple to find what you want. Pay attention to the rectangled text in the pic.

Happy coding.

[image]

Comment: `.index()` is jQuery. You have to include the scripts first...what is the problem you had there...

Answer (score 0):

Get tab index and tab name using `javascript`

```
< script type="text/javascript">
        function onTabChanged(sender, e) <br> { <br>
            var curIndex = document.getElementById('lblCurTabNo');<br>
            var curName = document.getElementById('lblCurTabName');<br>
            curIndex.innerHTML = sender.get_activeTabIndex();<br>
            curName.innerHTML = sender.get_activeTab().get_headerText();<br>
        }<br>
    < /script><br><br>

< asp:TabContainer ID="TabContainer1" runat="server" ActiveTabIndex="0" UseVerticalStripPlacement="false"
            Width="400px" BackColor="ActiveBorder" ForeColor="Green" OnClientActiveTabChanged="onTabChanged"><br>
    ----asp tab control-----------

< /asp:TabContainer>
```

Tab Index : `< asp:Label ID="lblCurTabNo" runat="server" Text="0"></asp:Label><br />`

Tab Name :`< asp:Label ID="lblCurTabName" runat="server" Text="Personal Info"></asp:Label>`

Comment: useless, i need way to get index without sender's